# Undefined method `stub_connection' in RSpec test for ActionCable channel

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I have the following test:

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe MyChannel, type: :channel do
  let (:current_user) { User.first }

  it "subscribes to a unique room for the user" do
    stub_connection current_user: User.first
    subscribe
    expect(subscription).to be_confirmed
    expect(streams).to include("my_channel_#{current_user.id}")
  end
end
```

It fails with this error:

```
 Failure/Error: stub_connection current_user: User.first

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `stub_connection' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::MyChannel:0x00000000deadbeef>
 # ./spec/channels/my_channel_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

According to [the documentation](https://relishapp.com/palkan/action-cable-testing/docs/channel-specs/channel-spec#specifying-connection-identifiers) and all of the examples I've found, `stub_connection` should be available automagically in an RSpec channel test. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I needed to install the [action-cable-testing gem](https://github.com/palkan/action-cable-testing). As of when I'm writing this answer, this gem's functionality is [slated to be integrated directly into Rails at some point in Rails 6](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/23211#issuecomment-413219187).

After [installing the gem](https://github.com/palkan/action-cable-testing#installation), make sure to [require the gem in your `rails_helper.rb` file](https://github.com/palkan/action-cable-testing#rspec-usage):

> ## RSpec Usage
>
> First, you need to have rspec-rails installed.
>
> Second, add this to your `"rails_helper.rb"` after requiring `environment.rb`:
>
> `require "action_cable/testing/rspec"`